# Concatenation of the contents of the files with the particle names in the array

Tags: puppet

I have many files(on master) in dir with names file1.domain file2.domain file3.domain someanothername.domain
Domain always is the same.

I need defined type, that i can use like this.

```
mydefinedtype { "title":
    filenames => ["file1", "file2", "file3"],
    }
```

And it will create file on node with content of files
file1.domain file2.domain file3.domain

Comment: do you mean: the concatenation of the contents of the files with the names in the array?

Comment: With the particle names in array!

Comment: or a t least just of names in the array.

Answer (score 0):

i guess you mean that you want to deploy some files in your nodes.

if so, you can do as follows. this will copy file1,2,3 from your_module/files to the target directory:

```
$filenames = ["file1", "file2", "file3"]

define copy_file {
  file { "/targetdir/$name":
    source => 'puppet:///modules/your_module/$name',
  }
}

copy_file { $filenames }
```

see: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/file_serving.html